# update mysql row if timestamp is within last 5 mins

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord, discord.js

i'm trying to create a stats bot for discord but i am having some issues trying to get part of it to work.

What i am trying to do is record the number of messages sent per channel at 5 min intervals. In my bot i have the following code:

```
    // on message events
    bot.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    //update channel stats
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM channel_stats WHERE channel_id = '${message.channel.id}' AND date BETWEEN timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)) AND timestamp(NOW())`, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        let sql;

        if(rows.length < 1) {
            sql = `INSERT INTO channel_stats (channel_id, date, channel_name, channel_message_count) VALUES ('${message.channel.id}', NOW(), '${message.channel.name}', 1)`;
        } else {
            let channel_message_count = rows[0].channel_message_count;
            sql = `UPDATE channel_stats SET channel_message_count = ${channel_message_count + 1}, channel_name = '${message.channel.name}' WHERE channel_id = '${message.channel.id}'`;
        };

        connection.query(sql)
      });
```

however, the bot *always* inserts a new row and never updates an existing one.

I ran the sql query `SELECT * FROM channel_stats WHERE channel_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' AND date BETWEEN timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)) AND timestamp(NOW())` manually via phpmyadmin and this seems to be working correctly - only returns rows created within the last 5 mins.

I'm struggling to understand why the bot is constantly adding new rows. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: One possible cause can be, you scheduled the bot on interval of 5 min. In SQL you are querying for data since last 5 min. Think in different way what if CREATING CONNECTION to database, or EXECUTING SQL on database or returning data set to you will take more than 1 second of time. In that case rows.length will be always less than 1. I am assuming, debug it properly. might you get your answer.

Comment: **WARNING**: To avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) always escape *any* arbitrary data in your query by using [placeholder values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values).

Comment: @KKK well the bot runs in realtime not every 5 mins, i just want it update rows that were created in the last 5 mins. If no row was created in the last 5 mins, create a new one

tadman thanks for the heads up!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to resolve this myself, had the channel_id row as int(11) which was causing the channel_id to be truncated.

changed it to VARCHAR(30) and it's working perfectly now.

Comment: I would reccomend storing the channel ID as a VARCHAR type instead of BIGINT, as the channel ID's are strings not integers. try `console.log(123456789101112131, '123456789101112131')` to see why.